# How to validate radio button in android?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

This is my coding. I don't know how to validate the radio button. When I click the next button,it still can proceed eventhough the radio button is not clicked. Sorry for my bad English.Please help me. Thank you.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dengue_ques2);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupDengue2);
    yes2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonQues2); //the answer is yes
    no2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButtonQues2No); //the answer is no

    Next=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNextQues2); 

    yes2.setSelected(true);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            if (i == R.id.radioButtonQues2)
            {
                selectedType = yes2.getText().toString();
            }
            else if (i == R.id.radioButtonQues2No)
            {
                selectedType = no2.getText().toString();
            }
            /* this part does not work
            else if (i == R.id.radioButtonQues2.isChecked(false) && 
                     i ==  R.id.radioButtonQues2No.isChecked(false))
            {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Please choose 1 answer", 
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }*/
        }
    });

    Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(dengueQues2.this, dengueQues3.class);
            intent.putExtra("REST2", selectedType);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

    public void onClickYes2 (View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have select 1 to 3 days.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onClickNo2 (View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have select 3 to 14 days.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Since you default `yes2` to selected shouldn't you default your `selectedType` to `yes2.getText().toString()`?

Comment: I already change it to yes2.getText().toString(); but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are the radio buttons inside a radio group in your layout file? Since you have ` yes2.setSelected(true);` in your `onCreate` method one of the two radio buttons should always show as selected when running the application. Is this the case?

Comment: Just noticed you said you replaced it with `yes2.getText().toString()`. You don't want to replace it you need both! `yes2.setSelected(true); selectedType = yes2.getText().toString();`

Comment: Yes. Actually when I run the application, there is no default value for the radio button even though I have set it to "yes2.setSelected(true)".

Comment: Try using yes2.setChecked(true);

Comment: It works. Thank you! :)

Comment: But wait, it means that I have to removed this part "else if (i == R.id.radioButtonQues2.isChecked(false) && 
                     i ==  R.id.radioButtonQues2No.isChecked(false))
            {
             Toast.makeText(this, "Please choose 1 answer", 
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }"

Comment: Yes that Toast would no longer be needed since one of the Radio Buttons will always be selected. If you want to see the toast you should not default `yes2` to selected and properly handle no selection in your next button click listener

Comment: Oh okay.Got it. But if I want to use the toast, how should I do it in the next button click listener?

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `setChecked()` method not the `setSelected()` method on the radio button.

Also you need to default `selectedType  = yes2.getText().toString();` since you are setting that as the default selection in `onCreate()`.

```
yes2.setChecked(true);
selectedType = yes2.getText().toString();
```

EDIT showing how to use no default selection:

```
Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(yes2.isChecked() || no2.isChecked()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(dengueQues2.this, dengueQues3.class);
            intent.putExtra("REST2", selectedType);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please choose 1 answer", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```